# SQL Server MERGE with conditions not merging

Tags: sql-server, sql-merge

I'm trying to do a simple update of my table when the collector has different data than the final table.  I'm using the code below.  When the first `SELECT` runs it tells me that the two columns both have data in them.  After the `MERGE` statement runs, and I do the new `SELECT`, both of the columns are still showing as `NULL`.  The merge isn't updating anything.

Have I messed up the `MERGE` syntax somehow?

The production code I have also includes `WHEN NOT MATCHED` and other items.  This is just a small example to demonstrate the problem.

```sql
SELECT l.Region_Name, l.Region_Code
FROM dbo.Collector_Locations l
WHERE l.id = 1038

MERGE INTO dbo.Locations AS T
USING dbo.Collector_Locations S ON T.id = S.id

WHEN MATCHED AND (T.Region_Name <> S.Region_Name OR T.Region_Code <> S.Region_Code)     
    THEN 
        UPDATE SET T.Region_Name = S.Region_Name,
                   T.Region_Code = S.Region_Code;

SELECT l.Region_Name, l.Region_Code
FROM dbo.Locations l
WHERE l.id = 1038
```

Comment: Have you run a join query to make sure the ids match and there is data in the two columns after joining?

Comment: @JoeC Yes, you can see in my example that I selected a specific ID from both tables, and have data in both tables.  It just doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the query to accomodate NULL values:

```
MERGE dbo.Locations AS T
USING dbo.Collector_Locations S 
ON T.id = S.id
WHEN MATCHED AND (ISNULL(T.Region_Name,'a') <> S.Region_Name OR ISNULL(T.Region_Code,'a') <> S.Region_Code) THEN UPDATE SET
    T.Region_Name = S.Region_Name,
    T.Region_Code = S.Region_Code;
```

Apart from that, the syntax looks fine. This should do the trick.

**EDIT:**

I would however go for a UPDATE statement in this scenario:

```
UPDATE dbo.Locations
SET T.Region_Name = S.Region_Name,T.Region_Code = S.Region_Code
FROM dbo.Locations T 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Collector_Locations S 
        ON T.id = S.id AND (T.Region_Name <> S.Region_Name OR T.Region_Code <> S.Region_Code)
```

You could also take our the last set of join condition, since the expected end result is going to be the same:

```
UPDATE dbo.Locations
    SET T.Region_Name = S.Region_Name,T.Region_Code = S.Region_Code
    FROM dbo.Locations T 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Collector_Locations S 
            ON T.id = S.id
```

Comment: The `INTO` is just optional.  Having it or removing it makes no difference to the statement itself.  I removed it just to be sure and it makes no difference.

Comment: I just added an edit to my answer using just the UPDATE statement...Any specific reason why you didn't just use the UPDATE statement?

Comment: Because it's part of a much larger merge with more columns and a delete and an insert.  I was trying to break the issue down to the smallest item I could post.

Comment: It does not look like there is anything wrong with the Merge Statement Syntax you are using here...Are you sure about the mapping variable and the expected result?

Comment: Yup.  The `Collector_Locations` table has that ID with two string values.  The `Locations` table has that ID with two `NULL` values for those columns.

Comment: I think the NULL Values are creating the issue here :)

Comment: You can add an isnull in your condition to fix this...I am going to update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206996/discussion-between-gargoyle-and-cr7sms).